# AJAX request always results in Bad Request error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, server

I'm supposed to receive data from a server, change it, and then post it back to a validation link via http. I'm using jQuery with AJAX to get it done and everything on my part looks good but for whatever reason the server thinks it's a bad request... I would appreciate any help.

Here's the full file:

```js
var dating;
var finalDate;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
      url: "http://challenge.code2040.org/api/dating",
      type: "POST",
      data: {
        "token": "c8ec6d794bd7d33b7d19f33adf5f6744"
      },
      dataType: "json"
    })
    .done(function(data) {
      var temp = data,
        date,
        interval;
      $.each(temp, function(key, value) {
        if (key == "datestamp")
          date = new Date(value);
        if (key == "interval")
          interval = value;
      })

      $("#startDate").append(date.toISOString());
      $("#seconds").append(date.getTime() / 1000);
      $("#seconds").append("<br>");
      $("#seconds").append("<br>");
      $("#startDate").append("<br>");
      $("#startDate").append("<br>");
      $("#interval").append(interval);
      $("#interval").append("<br>");
      $("#interval").append("<br>");

      var seconds = date.getTime();
      seconds += (interval * 1000);

      finalDate = new Date(seconds);
      $("#finalDate").append(finalDate.toISOString());
      $("#finalDate").append("<br>");
      $("#finalDate").append("<br>");

      $("#finalSeconds").append(finalDate.getTime() / 1000);
      $("#finalSeconds").append("<br>");
      $("#finalSeconds").append("<br>");

      var timeBetween = (finalDate.getTime() - date.getTime()) / 1000;


      $("#timeBetween").append(timeBetween);
      $("#timeBetween").append("<br>");
      $("#timeBetween").append("<br>");

      var string = finalDate.toISOString();

      dating = {
        "token": "c8ec6d794bd7d33b7d19f33adf5f6744",
        "datestamp": string
      };

      $.ajax({
          url: "http://challenge.code2040.org/api/dating/validate",
          dataType: "json",
          data: dating,
          type: "POST",
        })
        .done(function(data) {
          reply = jqxhr.responseText;
          $("#reply").append("<br>");
          $("#reply").append(reply);
          $("#reply").append("<br>");
          $("#reply").append(textStatus);
        })

      .fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        if (jqxhr.status == 404) {
          $("#reply").append("page not found!");
        }
        reply = jqxhr.responseText;
        $("#reply").append(textStatus);
        $("#reply").append("<br>");
        $("#reply").append("<br>");
        $("#reply").append(reply);
        $("#reply").append("<br>");
        $("#reply").append("<br>");
        $("#validated").append("Error: ");
        $("#validated").append(errorThrown);
      })
    })
    .fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      if (jqxhr.status == 404) {
        $("#reply").append("page not found!");
      }
      reply = jqxhr.responseText;
      $("#reply").append(reply);
      $("#reply").append("<br>");
      $("#reply").append(textStatus);
      $("#validated").append(errorThrown);

      $.ajax({
          url: "http://challenge.code2040.org/api/dating/validate",
          dataType: "json",
          data: prefix,
          type: "POST",
        })
        .done(function(data) {
          reply = jqxhr.responseText;
          $("#reply").append(reply);
          $("#reply").append("<br>");
          $("#reply").append(textStatus);
        })
      .fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        if (jqxhr.status == 404) {
          $("#reply").append("page not found!");
        }
        reply = jqxhr.responseText;
        $("#reply").append(reply);
        $("#reply").append("<br>");
        $("#reply").append(textStatus);
        $("#validated").append(errorThrown);
      })
    })
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="Dating.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="startDate">Start Date:</div>
  <div id="seconds">Seconds:</div>
  <div id="interval">Interval:</div>
  <div id="finalDate">Final Date:</div>
  <div id="finalSeconds">Final Seconds:</div>
  <div id="timeBetween">Seconds Between:</div>
  <div id="reply">Reply:</div>
  <div id="validated"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does `data: JSON.stringify({"token": "c8ec6d794bd7d33b7d19f33adf5f6744"}),` make a difference?

Comment: The issue is the `/validate` call, which for some reason is returning 400 with the text: `That's not the right response. Try again.`, which makes no sense. Try checking the API docs to determine the correct request parameters

Comment: @epascarello There were several other challenges before this and the JSON data Ive been sending has stayed consistent.

Comment: @Rory I'm sure that the server is looking for a "token" key and "datestamp" key that needs to be formatted as a ISO 8601 date string

Comment: when calling validate you're passing prefix, but where is it declared? If nothing is passed in and it is a required parameter in you endpoint, it will return 400, unless you allow null values

Comment: @yopez83 that's in the fail method but I've changed it so that's not the problem